# How to remove 0:00:00 from the output of datetime.date() in python?

Tags: python, datetime

How to remove `0:00:00` from the output of `datetime.date()` function? For example:

```py
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year1 = now.strftime("%Y")
month2 = now.strftime("%m")
day3 = now.strftime("%d")
year = int(year1)
month = int(month2)
day = int(day3)
first_day = datetime.date(2021,8,1)
second_day = datetime.date(year,month,day)
daysleft = first_day - second_day
print(daysleft)
```

I get the output:

```
9 days, 0:00:00
```

If you didn't understand the question title, My main goal is to remove the `0:00:00` before the period (.). I've seen many other questions like this (in stack overflow/exchange and other websites), but it was nothing in python coding language.

Comment: `print(daysleft.days, 'days')`

Comment: and if you need to display in label in tkinter - `label["text"] = f'{daysleft.days} days'`

Comment: shorter `daysleft = first_day - now.date()` or `daysleft = first_day - datetime.date.today()`

Comment: BTW: instead of `year1 = now.strftime("%Y")` `year = int(year1)` you can get `now.year`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 1):

You can get just the days by asking for the `.days` attribute of a `datetime.timedelta` object. E.g.:

```
print('{} days'.format(daysleft.days))
```

Comment: actually i need for printing in tkinter if curious

Comment: I'm telling how many days ***till*** 2021-8-1

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is printing the output and you don't care about maintaining daysleft as a datetime object, you can always convert it to a string and `.split()` it like this:

```
print(str(daysleft).split(",")[0])
```

Comment: actually i need for printing in tkinter if curious

Comment: using in tkinter so i think it should be

daysleft2 = str(daysleft).split(",")[0])|

lbl = tk.Label(text=daysleft2)|

lbl.pack()| the character | is for separating lines in the code

Comment: Yup, that looks good. My code above is only printing the days left as you intended, but the way you're storing it into a new variable should work fine. If you don't need the original string (daysleft) you can always reassign it like `daysleft = str((str(daysleft).split(",")[0])` so you don't have any extra vars.

Answer (score 0):

`datetime` has many useful functions and values

To get only `days` you can `daysleft.days`

```
print(f'{daysleft.days} days')
```

but you can also reduce other code to

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
daysleft = first_day - now.date()
```

or

```
today = datetime.date.today()
daysleft = first_day - today
```

---

**BTW:**

If you need `year`, `month`, `day` as numbers then you can get it as

```
year   = now.year
month  = now.month
day    = now.day
hour   = now.hour
minute = now.minute
second = now.second
ms     = now.microsecond
weekday = now.weekday()    # 0 = monday, ..., 6 = sunday
weekday = now.isoweekday() # 1 = monday, ..., 7 = sunday
```

Other useful function `timedelta`

```
one_day = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

today = datetime.date.today()

yesterday = today - one_day
tomorrow  = today + one_day

day_after_tomorrow = today + 2*one_day
```

---

Minimal working code with `tkinter`

```
import datetime

first_day = datetime.date(2021, 8, 1)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
daysleft = first_day - now.date()

today = datetime.date.today()
daysleft = first_day - today

print(f'{daysleft.days} days')

# ---

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
lbl = tk.Label(root, text=f'{daysleft.days} days till {first_day}')
lbl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```