# Python datetime: convert milliseconds to string, preserving zeroes

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

I'd like to convert a number of milliseconds to a formatted string using Python's datetime.

```
def milliseconds_to_str(t):
     """Converts the number of milliseconds to HH:MM:SS,ms time"""
     return str(datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=t)).replace('.', ',')[:-3]
```

The above works extremely well, for example:

```
> milliseconds_to_str(8712313): '2:25:12,313'
```

The problem arises when the number of milliseconds is an even multiple of 1000, for example:

```
milliseconds_to_srt_time(1000) > 0:00 (Should be 0:00:01,000)
milliseconds_to_srt_time(1000000) > 0:16 (Should be 0:16:00,000)
milliseconds_to_srt_time(4000400) > 1:06:40,400 (GOOD)
milliseconds_to_srt_time(80808231) > 22:26:48,231 (GOOD)
milliseconds_to_srt_time(80808000) > 22:26 (Should be 22:26:00,000)
```

How can I avoid this rounding?

Comment: What if there is a negative value of milliseconds?

Comment: related: [format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 1):

Using a fixed slicing of `[:-3]` wouldn't work because the resulting string of the milliseconds varies.

```
2:25:12.313000
0:00:01
```

Here, it will only be applicable to the 1st (where the last `000` would be trimmed resulting to `2:25:12.313`) but should **not** be applied on the 2nd (as that would remove `:01` resulting to `0:00`).

Instead, we can just append a `".000"` first and then trim the milliseconds part (which is after the dot `.`) to the first 3 characters `[:3]`.

```
import datetime

def milliseconds_to_srt_time(t):
     """Converts the number of milliseconds to HH:MM:SS,ms time"""
     time_str = str(datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=t)) + ".000"
     time_str_split = time_str.split(".", maxsplit=1)
     return f"{time_str_split[0]},{time_str_split[1][:3]}"

print(milliseconds_to_srt_time(8712313))
print(milliseconds_to_srt_time(1000))
print(milliseconds_to_srt_time(1000000))
print(milliseconds_to_srt_time(4000400))
print(milliseconds_to_srt_time(80808231))
print(milliseconds_to_srt_time(80808000))
```

**Output**

```
2:25:12,313
0:00:01,000
0:16:40,000
1:06:40,400
22:26:48,231
22:26:48,000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another exemple of implementation, very similar though.

You can find other usefull information here : [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

```
import datetime

def milliseconds_to_str(t):
    """Converts the number of milliseconds to HH:MM:SS,ms time"""
    d = str(datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=t)).split(".")
    out = ":".join(["%02d" % (int(float(x))) for x in d[0].split(':')])
    return out + "," + ("%d" % (int(d[1])/1000) if len(d)==2 else "000")

print(milliseconds_to_str(8712313))
print(milliseconds_to_str(1000))
print(milliseconds_to_str(1000000))  
print(milliseconds_to_str(4000400)) 
print(milliseconds_to_str(80808231)) 
print(milliseconds_to_str(80808000))
```

The output is the same as Niel gave.

Comment: Why derive the output from the str repr of the timedelta object? Wouldn't it be more intuitive to derive directly from the timedelta object, e.g. its total_seconds attribute as shown in the question you linked?