# Python print time as days and hours

Tags: python, datetime, time

Need to format time into a readable format like:
input:

> > > print(uptime)
> > > 21 days, 7:35:25.686738

desired output:
21 days, 7 hours

Comment: Is a type of `uptime` datetime?

Comment: How did you define `uptime` in the first place?

Comment: yes:
>>> print(type(uptime))
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
>>>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
date_str = str(uptime)
days, times = date_str.split(", ")
result = days
times = times.split(":")
units = ["hours", "minutes", "seconds"]
for i, unit in enumerate(units):
    result += f", {times[i]} {unit}"
print(result)
```

Basically, I'm constructing the string manually here.