# Python Datetime: Converting seconds to hours/minutes/seconds - but converting the day option into hours also?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Pretty basic question. I'm using a function that parses seconds from JSON and uses datetime in Python to output to hours/minutes/seconds, like so:

```
str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds here))
```

This outputs something like so:

```
Timestamp: 23:54:02.513000
Timestamp: 1 day, 0:01:07.827000
```

It works perfectly, but I don't want datetime to print "1 day", I want hours only. So for example the second above should be something like 24:01:07.827000

I tried using my own custom function to convert the seconds, but I feel there must be an easier way.

Comment: I think there isn't a built in function. But there is an implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320260/6871685

Answer (score 1):

According to Python Docs, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

> Only days, seconds and microseconds are stored internally.

So you have to compute the hours and minutes yourself using days and seconds. Below code uses f-strings.

```
import datetime

t = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60*60*24 + 11569) # A random number for testing

print(t) # 1 day, 3:12:49
print(f'{t.days * 24 + t.seconds // 3600:02}:{(t.seconds % 3600) // 60:02}:{t.seconds % 60:02}') # 27:12:49
```