# Python: TimeDelta how to show only minutes and seconds

Tags: python, time, format, string-formatting

I have the following code:

```
if (len(circles[0, :])) == 5:
            start = time.time()

        if (len(circles[0, :])) == 1:
            end = time.time()

            print(str(timedelta(seconds=end-start)))
```

This is the output:

```
0:01:03.681325
```

And this is the output i am looking to achieve:

```
1:03
```

Comment: Maybe use `\b` escape sequence?

Comment: Can you give us more debugging details? I can't test the code.

Comment: Seems like `timedelta.__format__` would be a good addition to the type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: import time
from datetime import timedelta


start = time.time()

time.sleep(3.681325)


end = time.time()

print(str(timedelta(seconds=end-start)))                                                                                                         You could use this code to try for yourself... i haven't managed to find a solution yet unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on just the default string representation of a `timedelta` object, you will get that format. Instead, you will have to specify your own formatting:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def convert_delta(dlt: timedelta) -> str:
    minutes, seconds = divmod(int(dlt.total_seconds()), 60)
    return f"{minutes}:{seconds:02}"

# this is your time from your code
dlt = timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=3, milliseconds=681.325)

print(convert_delta(dlt))
```

And with this you get this output:

```
1:03
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work as i am using live data for this program.. i cannot input the time into the code as it changes every time

Comment: @Ethan0619 This was just an example of how to do the calculation, with a minimum code sample. I just converted the code to make the conversion a method. You can put the `convert_delta` method into your code and call it with your deltas and print the result.

Answer (score 1):

That's all you gotta do!

```py
import time
from datetime import timedelta


start = time.time()
time.sleep(3.681325)
end = time.time()

print(str(timedelta(seconds=end - start)).split('.')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on wkl's answer, you could input the minutes, seconds, using `int(input())` and milliseconds using `float(input())`.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply printing a slice of the string? For example:

```
# Convert timedelta to string:
td_str = str(timedelta(seconds=end-start))

# Starting index of slice is the position of the first number in td_str that isn't '0':
starting_numbers = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}
for character_index, character in enumerate(td_str):
    if character in starting_numbers:
        start_slice_index = character_index
        break

# End of slice is always '.':
end_slice_index = td_str.index(".")

# Make sure that time still displays as '0:xx' when time goes below one minute:
if end_slice_index - start_slice_index <= 3:
    start_slice_index = end_slice_index - 4

# Print slice of td_str:    
print(td_str[start_slice_index:end_slice_index])
```

The advantage of this solution would be that if the time happens to go over one hour, the printed time still displays correctly.