# Python Datetime Subtraction include 0 to hour section

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, timedelta, python-dateutil

I've 2 strings of datetime, I need to subtract those to get duration but when subtracted for hour section it only contain 1 digit eg: 1:30, 2:30 So, my question is can we get subtracted datetime or string which includes 0 at the beginning eg: 01:30, 02:30.
Only for 1 - 9 hours include 0.
Assume that there will be no recording with a length of more than a day.

```
d1 = '2022-12-10T08:59:02Z'
d2 = '2022-12-10T10:06:35Z'
```

For subtraction I use the code below.

```
from dateutil import parser

parsed_d1 = parser.parse(d1)
parsed_d2 = parser.parse(d2)

result = str(parsed_d2 - parsed_d1)
print(result)
>>> '1:07:33'
```

If you want to use datetime strptime or strftime then the format is

```
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%Sz'
```

Currently I'm getting the desired output by doing this

```
duration_list = result.split(":")
if int(duration_list[0]) <= 9:
    result = f"0{result}"
print(result)
>>> '01:07:33'
```

Comment: You'll probably need to write your own converter; see [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Yeah i'm currently using formatting. i'll share in question itself. But its not a good solution which I'm using I guess. let me know anyway.

Comment: how do you want to format a duration that spans more than one day?

Comment: Sorry i'll update the question. You can assume that there will be no duration more than a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the duration spans less than one day**, you can also use `strftime`, after adding the duration to a datetime object where hours, minutes etc. are all zero, e.g. [datetime.min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.min). Ex:

```py
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime('2022-12-10T08:59:02Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
d2 = datetime.strptime('2022-12-10T10:06:35Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

print((datetime.min + (d2-d1)).strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
# 01:07:33
```

Btw. this is similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50295735/10197418) to the question I linked in the comments.

Comment: It will be more apparent if you add an explanation to DateTime.min

Comment: @jeevu94 added link to docs :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it does not seem that there is no built in one liner. So in this case you can convert your datetime delta to seconds and than format it by manually counting h,m, seconds. One way would be to use python built-in function `divmod()`:

```
from dateutil import parser


d1 = '2022-12-10T08:59:02Z'
d2 = '2022-12-10T10:06:35Z'

parsed_d1 = parser.parse(d1)
parsed_d2 = parser.parse(d2)

result = parsed_d2 - parsed_d1
# part from SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/539360/7489397
```

First we get total number of seconds (4053):

```
seconds = result.total_seconds()
```

After that calculate hours with `divmod` - result is 1h(`hour`) and 453seconds (`remainder`)

```
hours, remainder = divmod(seconds, 3600)
```

After that minutes - 7minutes(`minutes`), and 33seconds(`seconds`)

```
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

print('{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)))
```

Comment: Can you please add the explanation as well?