# Finding the index of a sub dataframe and match in the main dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

| CallID | StorageDate | CloseDate | Time Delta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-08 14:35:09 | 2023-02-08 14:35:56 |  |
| 1 | 2023-02-08 14:35:56 | 2023-02-08 14:42:00 | value |
| 2 | 2023-02-07 10:17:18 | 2023-02-07 10:22:23 |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-07 10:22:23 | 2023-02-07 15:09:14 |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-07 15:09:14 | 2023-02-07 16:20:50 |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-07 16:20:49 | 2023-02-08 09:23:16 |  |
| 2 | 2023-02-08 09:23:16 | 2023-02-08 09:27:21 | value |
| 3 | 2023-03-10 10:31:25 | 2023-03-10 10:41:37 |  |
| 3 | 2023-03-10 10:41:37 | 2023-03-10 14:23:18 | value |

To achieve the Time Delta, I am doing the following:

```
delta_time = a.iloc[-1]['CloseDate'] - a.iloc[0]['StorageDate']
```

I need to subtract the last CloseDate from the first StorageDate for each CallID (a total of  16821), and the delta_time must go in the last row of each CallID, where there is value (the same as I get the CloseDate from).

I'm doing as follows:

```
callid = 1
while callid <= 16821:
    df1 = df1[df1['CallID'] == callid]
    delta_time = df1.iloc[-1]['CloseDate'] - df1.iloc[0]['StorageDate']
    callid += 1
```

But the problem is that I'm not being abble to parse the delta_time value to the correct row.

Before I tried doing with loc and iloc, and I managed to send it to the correct row in df1 with the following structure:

```
 delta_time = df1.iloc[-1]['CloseDate'] - df1.iloc[0]['StorageDate']
 df1.loc[1, 'Time Delta'] = delta_time
```

It works, but it's unefficient since I have to change the value inside the loc for every different CallID and iloc[-1] doesn't seem to work. Moreover, I don't know how to parse it to the main dataframe and not only the one I created to do the math.

Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df[['StorageDate', 'CloseDate']] = df[['StorageDate', 'CloseDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

g = df.groupby('CallID')

df['Time Delta'] = (g['CloseDate'].transform('last')
                    .sub(g['StorageDate'].transform('first'))
                    .where(~df['CallID'].duplicated(keep='last'))
                   )
```

Output:

```
   CallID         StorageDate           CloseDate      Time Delta
0       1 2023-02-08 14:35:09 2023-02-08 14:35:56             NaT
1       1 2023-02-08 14:35:56 2023-02-08 14:42:00 0 days 00:06:51
2       2 2023-02-07 10:17:18 2023-02-07 10:22:23             NaT
3       2 2023-02-07 10:22:23 2023-02-07 15:09:14             NaT
4       2 2023-02-07 15:09:14 2023-02-07 16:20:50             NaT
5       2 2023-02-07 16:20:49 2023-02-08 09:23:16             NaT
6       2 2023-02-08 09:23:16 2023-02-08 09:27:21 0 days 23:10:03
7       3 2023-03-10 10:31:25 2023-03-10 10:41:37             NaT
8       3 2023-03-10 10:41:37 2023-03-10 14:23:18 0 days 03:51:53
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CallID': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                   'StorageDate': ['2023-02-08 14:35:09', '2023-02-08 14:35:56', '2023-02-07 10:17:18', '2023-02-07 10:22:23', '2023-02-07 15:09:14', '2023-02-07 16:20:49', '2023-02-08 09:23:16', '2023-03-10 10:31:25', '2023-03-10 10:41:37'],
                   'CloseDate': ['2023-02-08 14:35:56', '2023-02-08 14:42:00', '2023-02-07 10:22:23', '2023-02-07 15:09:14', '2023-02-07 16:20:50', '2023-02-08 09:23:16', '2023-02-08 09:27:21', '2023-03-10 10:41:37', '2023-03-10 14:23:18']})

df[['StorageDate', 'CloseDate']] = df[['StorageDate', 'CloseDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

Comment: In my case, even the ones that should have a value appear as NaT.

Comment: @Gustavo I added a reproducible input, can you first check that this works with that? If not, please provide your pandas version. If this does work but not your real data, please update the example

Comment: Is it supposed to print the dataframe? If so, yes, it worked.

Comment: @Gustavo can you test my code on it. The other answer used the exact same logic as mine, so I'm very surprised that this wouldn't work. Make sure to use the latest version

Comment: now it worked just fine :) Thanks!
Another question: how can I change time delta to only have data as hh:mm:ss and not "x days hh:mm:ss"?

Comment: @Gustavo it depends if you can have a timedelta greater than 24h. Is this the case? Then do you want to truncate or have hours greater than 24? There is already a question on that

Comment: @Gustavo found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for filter last rows generated by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
m = ~df['CallID'].duplicated(keep='last')

g = df.groupby('CallID')

df.loc[m, 'Time Delta'] = (g['CloseDate'].transform('last')[m]
                                         .sub(g['StorageDate'].transform('first')[m]))
print (df)
   CallID         StorageDate           CloseDate       Time Delta
0       1 2023-02-08 14:35:09 2023-02-08 14:35:56              NaN
1       1 2023-02-08 14:35:56 2023-02-08 14:42:00  0 days 00:06:51
2       2 2023-02-07 10:17:18 2023-02-07 10:22:23              NaN
3       2 2023-02-07 10:22:23 2023-02-07 15:09:14              NaN
4       2 2023-02-07 15:09:14 2023-02-07 16:20:50              NaN
5       2 2023-02-07 16:20:49 2023-02-08 09:23:16              NaN
6       2 2023-02-08 09:23:16 2023-02-08 09:27:21  0 days 23:10:03
7       3 2023-03-10 10:31:25 2023-03-10 10:41:37              NaN
8       3 2023-03-10 10:41:37 2023-03-10 14:23:18  0 days 03:51:53
```

Another solution with aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with mapping difference:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))

m = ~df['CallID'].duplicated(keep='last')

df1 = df.groupby('CallID').agg({'CloseDate':'last', 'StorageDate':'first'})

df.loc[m, 'Time Delta'] = (df.loc[m, 'CallID'].map(df1['CloseDate'].sub(df1['StorageDate']))
                             .apply(f))
print (df)
   CallID         StorageDate           CloseDate Time Delta
0       1 2023-02-08 14:35:09 2023-02-08 14:35:56        NaN
1       1 2023-02-08 14:35:56 2023-02-08 14:42:00   00:06:51
2       2 2023-02-07 10:17:18 2023-02-07 10:22:23        NaN
3       2 2023-02-07 10:22:23 2023-02-07 15:09:14        NaN
4       2 2023-02-07 15:09:14 2023-02-07 16:20:50        NaN
5       2 2023-02-07 16:20:49 2023-02-08 09:23:16        NaN
6       2 2023-02-08 09:23:16 2023-02-08 09:27:21   23:10:03
7       3 2023-03-10 10:31:25 2023-03-10 10:41:37        NaN
8       3 2023-03-10 10:41:37 2023-03-10 14:23:18   03:51:53
```

Comment: @GustavoFelippedeOliveira - You are welcome. I hope second solution working well too.

Comment: @GustavoFelippedeOliveira - Answer was edited for `HH:MM:SS` values

Comment: thank you very much! It worked as well, and thanks for noticing my request on the other answer. I'm new to programing and both python and pandas are being a challenge for me.